# C - using malloc for an address of a char**

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to create a tic tac toe game by C, and i have a function to create the game board:

```
void createBoard(char*** board, int size)
{   
    int i, j;
    *(board) = malloc(size * sizeof( char* ));
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *(board)[i] = malloc(size * sizeof(char));
    }

    printf("Default board:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            *(board)[i][j] = '-';
            printf("%c", *(board)[i][j]);
            printf("  ");
            if((j + 1) % size  == 0)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

in main function, i pass to this function an address of a char**:

```
int main()
{
    int size;
    char** board = NULL;
    char userInp;

    sizeOfBoard(&size);

    createBoard(&board, size);
}
```

and i use *(board) to access the value of the pointer (which is NULL at first) and then assign malloc returned address to it but i don't know why it doesn't work. Can someone help me fixing this issue.

Comment: what does `sizeOfBoard(&size);` set in `size` ?

Comment: The basic guidance is that if you use 3 stars anywhere you're doing it very wrong.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what about 4 stars?

Comment: Use `(*board)` in the function, not `*(board)`, since the meaning is different if using array subscripting (i.e  `*(board)[i]` is not the same thing as `(*board)[i]`, but you're using it like it is).

Comment: All of your dereferences are wrong. `*(board)[i]` dereferences the wrong pointer, should be `(*board)[i]` or `board[0][i]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre and could you demonstrate 4 stars without having 3 stars ;)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it changes the size variable. Like if the user want a 4x4 table, size will be 4.

Comment: In any case you wouldn't have this problem if you just returned `char **` *or* used `char **` in the function only assigning `*board` at the end.

Comment: @ThuanNguyen that is another perfect example of incorrectly using pass by reference. `int size = get_board_size();`.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: 4 stars consist of a star and three stars. Recursive grammar definition.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: C does **not** support pass-by-reference. **Never ever**

Answer (score 2):

Do not do it that way.  Instead, create a structure that describes the board and the state of the board, and use that.  Within the structure, use an one-dimensional array for the board state:

```
typedef struct {
    int   rows;
    int   cols;
    char *cell;
}  board;
#define  BOARD_INIT  { 0, 0, NULL }

#define  CELL(b, r, c) ((b).cell[(c) + (r)*(b).cols])
```

To create a board, you can use e.g.

```
int  create_board(board *b, const int rows, const int cols)
{
    const size_t  cells = (size_t)rows * (size_t)cols;
    const size_t  bytes = sizeof (board) + cells * sizeof (b->cell[0]);

    if (!b) {
        /* No board specified. */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }

    b->rows = 0;
    b->cols = 0;
    b->cell = NULL;

    if (rows < 1 || cols < 1) {
        /* Invalid size. */
        errno = EINVAL;
        return -1;
    }
    if ((size_t)(cells / (size_t)rows) != (size_t)cols ||
        (size_t)((bytes - sizeof (board)) / cells) != sizeof (b->cell[0])) {
        /* Board is too large. */
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }

    b->cell = malloc(bytes);
    if (!b->cell) {
        /* Board was too large. */
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return -1;
    }

    b->rows = rows;
    b->cols = cols;

    return 0;
}

void  free_board(board *b)
{
    if (b) {
        free(b->cell);
        b->rows = 0;
        b->cols = 0;
        b->cell = NULL;
    }
}
```

You can either use the `CELL(board, row, column)` access macro, or the below safe accessor functions:

```
char  get_cell(board *b, const int r, const int c, const char outside)
{
    if (!b || r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= b.rows || c >= b.cols)
        return outside;
    else
        return b->cell[r*b->cols + c];
}

void set_cell(board *b, const int r, const int c, const char value)
{
    if (b && r >= 0 && c >= 0 && r < b.rows && c < b.cols)
        b->cell[r*b->cols + c] = value;
}
```

Neither `get_cell()` or `set_cell()` will try to access outside the actual board. (The fourth parameter, `outside`, for `get_cell()` defines the result value if you try to access an invalid board, or outside the board.)

---

To be honest, I do prefer to use a C99 flexible array member for the cell array.  In that case, the structure is something like

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct {
    int            rows;
    int            cols;
    unsigned char  cell[];
} board;
```

The `board` type is then somewhat similar to `FILE` stream handles: you never declare them statically (`board b;` or `FILE f;`), but use a pointer to one (`board *b`, `FILE *f`).  To create a new board, you could use e.g.

```
board *create_board(const int rows, const int cols)
{
    board        *b;
    const size_t  cells = (size_t)rows * (size_t)cols;
    const size_t  bytes = cells * sizeof (b->cell[0]);
    const size_t  total = bytes + sizeof (board);

    /* Check for invalid size */
    if (rows < 1 || cols < 1) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Check for size overflow */
    if ((size_t)(cells / (size_t)rows) != (size_t)cols ||
        (size_t)(bytes / cells) != sizeof (b->cell[0]) ||
        total <= bytes) {
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Allocate memory for the whole board */
    b = malloc(total);
    if (!b) {
        /* Failed. Too large. */
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Optional: Clear the entire structure. */
    memset(b, 0, total);

    /* Initialize the board fields. */
    b->rows = rows;
    b->cols = cols;

    return b;
}

void free_board(board *b)
{
    if (b) {
        b->rows = 0;
        b->cols = 0;
        free(b);
    }
}
```

In C99, we can declare our accessor functions as `static inline`, which means they are only visible in the same translation unit (so you'd declare these in the header file that declares the `board` structure too), and is also a hint to the C compiler that it should inline these.  Basically, `static inline` functions should be as fast as preprocessor macros, but also provide type safety.

```
static inline int get_cell(board *b, const int row, const int col,
                           const int outside)
{
    if (!b || row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= b->rows || col >= b->cols)
        return outside;
    else
        return b->cell[row * b->cols + col];
}

static inline int  set_cell(board *b, const int row, const int col,
                            const int value, const int outside)
{
    if (b && row >= 0 && col >= 0 && row < b->rows && col < b->cols)
        return b->cell[row * b->cols + col] = value;
    else
        return outside;
}
```

To print the board (using `|`, `+`, and `-` as lines between cells), you could use e.g.

```
static int board_char(board *b, const int row, const int col)
{
    if (b && row >= 0 && col >= 0 &&
        row < b->rows && col < b->cols) {
        const int  value = b->cell[row * b->cols + col];
        if (isprint(value))
            return value;
        else
            return ' ';
    } else
        return ' ';
}

void print_board(FILE *out, board *b)
{
    if (out && b && b->rows > 0 && b->cols > 0) {
        const int  lastrow = b->rows - 1;
        const int  lastcol = b->cols - 1;
        int        r, c;

        for (r = 0; r < lastrow; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < lastcol; c++) {
                fputc(board_char(b, r, c), out);
                fputc('|', out);
            }
            fputc(board_char(b, r, lastcol), out);
            fputc('\n', out);

            for (c = 0; c < lastcol; c++) {
                fputc('-', out);
                fputc('+', out);
            }
            fputc('-', out);
            fputc('\n', out);
        }

        for (c = 0; c < lastcol; c++) {
            fputc(board_char(b, lastrow, c), out);
            fputc('|', out);
        }
        fputc(board_char(b, lastrow, lastcol), out);
        fputc('\n', out);
    }
}
```

where `board_char()` returns a descriptive character corresponding to the referred to cell.  The above version checks if the value in the array is a printable character, and if it is, returns it; otherwise, including characters outside the board, it returns a space.  Instead of the `if (isprint(value))`, you could use a `switch (value) { ... }` with `case` statements of each of the values you use for each cell.

(For example, if zero indicates unused/free, 1 indicates first player (say `X`), and 2 indicates second player (say `O`), you could use 3 for "blocked", marking some cells unusable, making the game much more interesting.)

You could use a wide Curses library (for example, ncursesw) to make your game interactive in the terminal, and use nice box drawing characters to draw the game board. For example,

```
┌───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
│ X │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │ O │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │   │
├───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
│   │   │   │   │   │
└───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
```

You can use localization and wide character support to print the above kind of boards to the terminal, without using a Curses library, but unfortunately there will be issues in Windows. (As of this speaking, Microsoft is still working on proper Unicode support for terminal/console applications, without requiring the use of Microsoft-specific C extensions.)